# Error opening project in VS2013Pro from VS2013Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I wrote a WebSite Project and a Web Api Project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

Now I installed additional to VS2013Web from my MSDN subscription Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

When I try to open my Projects in Pro, I get an error:

`The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project.WebProjectPackage,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project package did not load correctly.`

I should have a look into my ActivityLog.xml.

And there is:

```
<entry>
  <record>273</record>
  <time>2014/04/08 08:37:13.725</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project.WebProjectPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project]</description>
  <guid>{AAB75614-2F8F-4DA6-B0A6-763C6DBB2969}</guid>
  <hr>80070002</hr>
  <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureAD.Contracts, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>274</record>
  <time>2014/04/08 08:37:13.730</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project.WebProjectPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project]</description>
  <guid>{AAB75614-2F8F-4DA6-B0A6-763C6DBB2969}</guid>
  <hr>80070002</hr>
  <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureAD.Contracts, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

I still have VS2013Web installed. If I open my Project with this Version, everything is fine.
Any ideas, how to fix the Problem?

Might this error Comes up, because VS2013Web is in german and VS2013Pro is in english?

I tried also in NuGet Console:

`Update-Package -Reinstall`

But this breaks my web Project totally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureAD.Contracts...

"Azure" is surely the keyword here, Express does not support Azure out of the box.  As described in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee405484.aspx), the Azure Tools must be installed and you must have the Web version of Express.

It is a separate download.  You'll find the VS2013 Express for Web version of it [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/), pick the upper left one to get the installer.

Comment: It´s vice versa: Pro shows this message - not Express. I´ve worked till now with Express very well an want now use Pro.

Comment: Well, same story, you still need the Azure Tools installed.  Repeat it so the Pro edition gets configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this -

1. Close Visual Studio 2013
2. Click the TOOLS--->VISUAL STUDIO COMMAND PROMPT   to open the command window
3. Input the command "devenv /Setup"
4. Restart Visual Studio 2013

Comment: It seems, that I have Trouble with the Web Developer Tools in VS. Clicking on Server Explorer -> Azure -> an error about the Tools pops up. I try to repair VS2013Pro once again.

Comment: It´s the same error message like in my question. It comes up when I try to open Server Explorer -> Windows Azure -> Web Sites.

Repair of installation failed. Error because another IIS 8.0 is installed on my System (sure: from VS2013Web). But I don´t want to uninstall now VS2013Web, because this VS is running perfectly till now...

Comment: More Details in Server Explorer: Microsoft Web Developer Tools is not installed correctly. Please re-install or repair the product.

Comment: Load Visual Studio in safe mode:                                \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\IDE>devenv /safemode                                                           and un-install the productivity tools.